# How to set array in xml attribute

Tags: javascript

I have an tag attribute like

```
<Tag V = "Val4;Val5"></Tag>
```

Here `Val1`,`Val2` is one value and `Val3` is a second.

Later in my code, they are taking `V` as a value of array so I am making it as a comma separated like this.

```
if(Tag.search(";") != -1){
    ValStr = ValStr.replace(";",",")
    Tag[i].setAttribute('V',ValStr);
}
```

There is no problem so far. My code taking `arr[val4,val5]`. But the problem is coming here.

In this case, it's reading three value. 
So for that, I am changing into an array but don't know how to attach this with XML tag.

```
if(Tag.search(",") != -1){
                debugger;
    TagArr = ftagValStr[i].split(";");
    }
```

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Instead of replacing ; by , - replace by some other character like - or * .

Comment: How that will be different ??